# how to add innerHTML in another row?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add a list of users under the "participants". My current code add the elements next to the work participants.

```
    showname.innerHTML = `<h4>participants:</h4>` + '<ul>' + users.map(function (user) {
        return '<li>' + user + '</li>';
    }).join('') + '</ul>';
```

So I like something like this:

participants:

-user1

-user2

-user3

but currently it is:

participants: user1 user2 user3

Answer (score 2):

There's not much wrong in your code unless you didn't assign selector properly. If you have a div with class container, here is what you should do without changing your code.

```
const showname = document.querySelector('.container');
const users = ['Solomon', 'Abebe', 'Sara'];
showname.innerHTML = '<h4>participants:</h4>' + '<ul>' + users.map(function (user) {
        return '<li>' + user + '</li>';
}).join('') + '</ul>';
```

The other option is to create html elements and append them on the existing

```
const containerBox = document.createElement('div');
containerBox.classList.add = 'container-box';
showname.appendChild(containerBox);
containerBox.innerHTML = '<h4>participants:</h4>' + '<ul>' + users.map(function (user) {
        return '<li>' + user + '</li>';
}).join('') + '</ul>';
```

As I said, there's not much you should change. I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks. The second option works for me!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply add `<br>` tag at the end of each user record?

```
showname.innerHTML = '<h4>participants:</h4><br>' + '<ul>' + users.map(function (user) {
    return '<li>' + user + '</li>' + '<br>';
}).join('') + '</ul>';
```

Comment: I tried exactly that. But it did not work. Maybe because something else in my other code. Thanks

Comment: It works fine in my code even without the `<br>` tag. You can share us more of your code to locate the mistake.

Comment: I like to add the "showname" element to the docuement body. ```    showname.innerHTML = `<h4>meeting participants:</h4>` + '<ul>' + users.map(function (user) {
        return '<li>' + user + '</li>';
    }).join('') + '</ul>';

    document.body.append(showname)``` before this I have ```const showname = document.createElement('div')```

Comment: or maybe because I have this css ```showname.classList.add('showname')```

Answer (score 0):

In JS you can create HTMl Elements by using createElement(tagName). Then you can use innerText or innerHTMl to add text to html to the element. Then you have to append to the parent element.

**working example**

```js
const ul = document.querySelector('ul');
const ps = ["p1","p2","p3"];
const h4 = document.createElement('h4');

ps.forEach(p => {
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  li.innerHTML = p;
  ul.appendChild(li)
})
```

```html
<h4>participants:</h4>
<ul></ul>
```